# Bootstrap 3 justified nav-pills with multiple lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like my Bootstrap nav-pills to be justified and also wrap to multiple lines.  For example, something like this:

```
[ (   Pill One  ) (  Pill Two  ) ( Pill Three ) ] 
[ (       Pill Four     ) (      Pill Five    ) ]
```

If I use this for my pills:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
```

then the pills wrap to multiple lines when needed, but the pills are not justified.

If use this for my pills:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
```

then they are justified, but the pills don't wrap to multiple lines (instead the text with a pill wraps to multiple lines).

I tried adding

```
.nav-pills li { white-space: nowrap; }
```

and this prevented the text from wrapping in the pills but now the pills overflow off the right side of the page.

Is there a way for the pills to be justified and also wrap?  I don't like the look of the unjustified pills when they wrap.

I should add that this is for user generated content so it needs to work for a variable number of pills and different text lengths in each.

Comment: Is there any possibility you could put each one into a column(s)?

Comment: @Crowes, weird, I was sure I had replied to your comment but now it is gone.  I'm ok with columns.  E.g., Pill Four under Pill One , Pill Five under Pill Two, and nothing under Pill Three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap examples of `nav-pills` all show the pills being generated using `<li>`.  It turns out you can get most of the `nav-pills` functionality even if you generate the pills in other ways.

I generated my pills using just the grid system and I take advantage of the fact that if you have more than 12 columns, the additional pills spill over gracefully to the next line.  Here is my template code to do this:

```
<div class="row">
{% for x in x_list %}
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
<div class="my-pill">
<a href="#panel-{{ loop.index0 }}" aria-controls="panel-{{ loop.index0}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-{{ loop.index0 }}">{{ x.title }}</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

My css for `my-pill` makes the pills look similar to the Bootstrap default.

Clicking on the pills as generated above allows switching between tabs.  The only thing that doesn't work is that the pills don't indicate which tab is active.  The Bootstrap Javascript for adding the "active" class to the pill for the shown tab doesn't work because that javascript is looking for `<li>`.  I can live with that.